# Partitions mounting in file manager but not showing in terminal

Tags: command-line, partitioning, mount, permissions, fstab

I was trying today to mount my partition directly from terminal and i found something on internet and ran these two commands in the terminal

- sudo mkdir /media/mountpoint
- sudo mount /dev/sdxx /media/mountpoint -o umask=000

Now i can't see my partitions in terminal though they are visible and accessed via file manager.

Comment: Ain't it mounted as /dev/sdxx in the first place?

Comment: @KenMollerup No. That's the device, not the mount point.

Comment: @an0nh4x0r Please specify what you mean by "Now i can't see my partitions in terminal though". You can see what's mounted by executing `df -h`. You can see the contents of what you mounted by first switching to the mount point via `cd /media/mountpoint` and then executing `ll`.

Comment: @UTF-8 ... i can browse the partitions via file manager but its not showing in terminal when i visit /media/username/ in terminal.

Comment: @an0nh4x0r Simply press `ctrl+L` to let yourself show the path Nautilus is at. If you have a newer version of Ubuntu, you can just also right-click in a folder and choose "Open in Terminal". If that's not possible in your Ubuntu version, you can install the package `nautilus-open-terminal` and restart Nautilus for the change to take effect via `sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal && nautilus -q`.

Comment: @UTF-8 thanks after pressing `ctrl+L` i got the path ... strange the path is now /mnt/ ... This is very strange ...My all three partitions are mounting at /mnt/ now as i have made them automount on startup.